# Fingerprinting remote OS : Python

Tags: python, security, sockets, network-scan, fingerprinting

I am trying to write a Python script that when given an IP address it will attempt to identify the OS of a remote host. I am aware Nmap will do this easily but I would like to try and write one in Python.

Having the ability to identify Linux/Windows/Mac etc would be great but would prefer to identify kernel version.

Any suggestions or directions that I may be able to investigate?

Comment: Start by googling "OS fingerprinting" perhaps?

Comment: You should look into nmap.

Comment: If nmap does what you want, why don't you take a look at the code and see what it does on the backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/) and p0f are your best bet. People have had differing results however.

http://blog.pierre.droids-corp.org/2008/01/scapy-using-p0f.html